# During the quest "Messages to the Nexus", what impact does editing the messages have?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

During the quest "Messages to the Nexus", you're sent to pick up messages from terminals that have been set up on the Angaran planet of Aya and upon picking up each collection of messages you're given the option to forward the messages to the Nexus unedited or edit the content and then forward.

[image: screenshot of the in game popup]

Regardless of which option you select on this screen the screen is dismissed and you get mission credit for collection messages from that location.

What impact does editing the messages have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you send the messages (edited) to the Nexus, you will receive an email from Director Tann. He will be suspicious of the messages if you edited them. Saying "he needed the 'unvarnished truth' in the hopes of avoiding miscalculations in future dealings with the Angara." He will pursue his own avenues to gather further information."

Not sure if this will have any future impact or not... or if its just a tiny task mission.

Comment: well I'd hope it would have more impact than that since it's about your diplomatic beginnings with a new species and this is an important plot line in the new game but it seems many of the "choices" in ME:A don't

Answer (score 0):

I sent them all off as is... and still got that email. So not sure if that part was bugged, or rigged (i.e. it was meant to be that way). This game has a lot of random quirks, and generally not in a good way. In the other Mass Effect games there were not as many problems of ''the wrong choice appearing so innocent'' (Maybe Later - Loses you the Quest). And worse yet there are problems with a few quests still even from 1.10 when they stopped patching, so never know if it's random bad choices or simply the game.

Comment: If you're not sure, then try to restrain to the parts you do know

Answer (score -1):

If you edit just one, Tann gets pissy. Makes me mad really